# Should/can the site start a campaign to solicit & engage qualified members?

Tags: discussion

As I mentioned in a couple other posts - it's entirely possible to find plenty of people in academia/government/corporate life/non-profits who really like to get involved on this topic.  Should this site make an effort to collect question, launch good questions, and then organize/conduct a campaign to find answers from qualified individuals?  That might jump-start some interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appart from the folks you attract through search (i.e. having high-quality content), your suggestion is ***the*** single best way to find and attract experts to your site!

#### So how do we do that?

We've all been there. Learn from our experiences:

[**A Recipe to Promote your Site**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

…and a bit more apt to this specific question:

[**Helping The Experts Get Answers**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/)

Answer (score 3):

I think the simple answer here is 'yes'.  Being a member of the original Stack Overflow, I can testify that this software is tuned for massive user involvement.  There's no reason not to get people involved - best I can see.

Comment: +1 Testify!  Perhaps a separate question should be - what's the best way to set this up?  At any rate, if you're willing to augment I think it would be appropriate.

Comment: @JackRyan the best ways are: (1) follow Robert's links and learn from others' experience. (2) Try lots of different things; work out what works and what doesn't; and then carry on doing the things that work, and stop doing the things that don't work.